# How can my UI application correctly display an image and predict if a person has pneumonia or not?

Tags: python, computer-vision, project

I'm doing a Computer Vision project that uses deep learning for a pneumonia detector. I ran the training part with no issue, but when I try to test with my UI , the application closes after i upload a picture to the `UI` to predict if the person has pneumonia or not. This message returns Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

I want the `UI` to successfully predict if the person does indeed have pneumonia or not. But so far I am stuck with the problem of the model exiting after a picture is uploaded.

This is my `UI` code:

```
import warnings
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie

from win32com.client import Dispatch

def speak(str1):
    speak = Dispatch(("SAPI.SpVoice"))
    speak.Speak(str1)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(695, 609)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 611))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: #035874;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, -60, 541, 561))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.gif = QMovie("picture.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.gif)
        self.gif.start()
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 430, 591, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 530, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("patient.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                                       "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                       " background-color:#DF582C;\n"
                                       "}\n"
                                       "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                       " background-color: #7D93E0;\n"
                                       "}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 530, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                                         "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                         " background-color:#DF582C;\n"
                                         "}\n"
                                         "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                         " background-color: #7D93E0;\n"
                                         "}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        # New QLabel to display the uploaded image
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 10, 400, 400))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.upload_image)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.predict_result)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PNEUMONIA Detection App"))
        self.label.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/newPrefix/picture.gif\"/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Chest X-ray PNEUMONIA Detection"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Upload Image"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Prediction"))

    def upload_image(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if filename:
            path = str(filename)
            print(path)
            self.img_path = path
            self.model = load_model('chest_xray.h5')

            # Display the uploaded image
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaledToWidth(400)  # Adjust the width as needed
            self.label_3.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def predict_result(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'img_path'):
            img_file = image.load_img(self.img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
            x = image.img_to_array(img_file)
            x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
            img_data = preprocess_input(x)
            result = self.model.predict(img_data)

            print(result)
            if result[0][0] > 0.5:
                print("Result is Normal")
                speak("Result is Normal")
            else:
                print("Affected By PNEUMONIA")
                speak("Affected By PNEUMONIA")
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self.frame, 'Warning', 'Please upload an image first.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This message returns and the program stops altogether: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).